# vespa json object changes to string

Tags: database, deployment, server, vespa, database-versioning

i have vespa verion 5.220.14 installed in one server where i have used json (provided by gson lib ) in searcher, while i am deploying the same code in vespa version 5.550 in a diffrentserver it is not working and changing it to string.
Attached are the screenshot for same.
What could be the possible reason for same,
And what should be resolution to make this work. [image: the result in server where vespa 5.550 is installed]

[image: the resul of dtaa type in object in server where vespa version is 5.220.14]

Comment: I assume these are 7.* versions, not 5.* versions?

Comment: Is this a hit generated by Vespa content, or is it perhaps added in code by DedupeIndividualSearcher? If the former, how is the "data" field defined in your schema in the application package. If the latter, what does the code that adds this data look like?

Comment: JsonObject resdata = root.get("responseData").getAsJsonObject();
      
JSONObject newroot = new JSONObject(resdata.toString());
      
hit.setField("data", newroot);
      
hit.setField("responseCode", root.get("responseCode").getAsInt());





this is how we have implemented the code to add data as a json object in vespa logs its a json object only but in  postman its string

Answer (score 2):

special-handling of org.json in rendering was removed one year ago:

https://github.com/vespa-engine/vespa/pull/16326/files#diff-8cff528a21faf96a6e90b1490adc25ff474ad72e973627ee4e8b9734084ad86f

you should probably wrap your "data" field in a facade that implements the com.yahoo.data.JsonProducer interface:

https://javadoc.io/doc/com.yahoo.vespa/container-search/latest/com/yahoo/data/JsonProducer.html

Comment: Hi Arne thanks for the response could you please share us the dependency to com.yahoo.data  as its giving me plugin error

Answer (score 1):

Arne is correct, we had to move this due to the license of org.json, sorry for the inconvenience.

To implement Arne's solution, all you need is to replace hit.setField("data", newroot); in your code by

```
hit.setField("data", (com.yahoo.data.JsonProducer)s -> s.append(resdata));
```